# How to match a pattern and a part of it at the same time in OCaml?

Tags: ocaml

I'm working on an exercise that requires me to compare the first and second element of a list, and then I need to make a recursion call on the tail.

If I use `h::t` then I can't access the second element, while using `first::second::t` makes it harder to access the original tail.

Is there any syntax I can use to match both at the same time?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `as` to bind a pattern or a part of it to a variable, this is known as an *alias pattern*, for reference this is described in chapter [7. Patterns](https://ocaml.org/manual/patterns.html) of the manual (https://ocaml.org/manual/)

```
* match [0;1;2] with 
| x::(y::t as s) -> (x,y,t,s) 
| _ -> failwith "no";

- : int * int * int list * int list = (0, 1, [2], [1; 2])
```